# Starting a new video when a image view is clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on an image box the video playing should stop the thread and start a new video. Currently, it's giving me an exception of "IllegalStateException".

How can I stop the thread and start a brand new video?

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView videoView;
MediaController mController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.introductie);
}

protected void onClick(View v)
{
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.imageView2:

            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.introductie);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView3:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.wel_iets_aan_de_hand3);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView4:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hoe_moet_je_plassen4);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView5:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.wanneer_moet_je_plassen5);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView6:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hoe_haak_moet_je_plassen6);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView7:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.piponormaalvrachtwagens7);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView8:
            playVideo("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pipoobstipatievrachtwagens8);
            break;
    }
}
protected void playVideo(String videoName)
{
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoViewId);
    mController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoName);
    mController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mController);
    videoView.start();
}
```

}

```
9-06 09:55:21.163 7107-7107/com.example.nepalibinod.catherina E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nepalibinod.catherina, PID: 7107
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method videoOne(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imageView2'
```

Comment: Could you edit the question adding the log info?

Comment: read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before post/Ask  any question on **stackoverflow **

Comment: "Could not find method videoOne(View)" check if you have added videoOne as onclick in xml

Comment: Can you make `onClick(View v)` from `protected` to `public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your OnClick listeners inside code (Java/Kotlin) instead of XML. What I assume happened is that you assigned an `android:onClick` to the button inside the XML but android can not find your method inside your code.

Try to `findViewById` your view and assign a ‍`setOnClickListener` to it.